# shell quivalent code for batch file

Tags: java, shell, jar, jvm

I got a batch file to convert into shell file
batch code is:

```
SETLOCAL

SET BASEDIR=C:\hhpps\HomeHealthGrouper
SET HH_CLASSPATH=.;%BASEDIR%\dist\HomeHealthJava.jar;.;%BASEDIR%\dist\HH_PPS_V_API.jar
rem SET JAVA_VERSION=-version:1.7
SET TEST_FILE=%BASEDIR%\TestData\TestDataV7118.txt

rem SET OPTIONS=details=1

java %JAVA_VERSION% -Xms512m -Xmx512m -Djava.util.logging.config.file="%BASEDIR%\config\logging.properties" ^
    -classpath "%HH_CLASSPATH%" com.mmm.cms.homehealth.test.HomeHealthGrouper_HP ^
    "input=%TEST_FILE%" "config=%BASEDIR%\config\HomeHealthGrouper.properties" ^
    %OPTIONS%

rem reset all variables to prevent locking
SET BASEDIR=
SET HH_CLASSPATH=
SET TEST_FILE=
SET OPTIONS=

 ENDLOCAL
```

For the above code i have written this shell code:

```
#!/bin/bash
export BASEDIR=/home/bitsbridge/Videos/HomeHealthGrouper
#export JAVA_HOME=/media    /bitsbridge/WIN XP/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0/bin/java
#export PATH=$PATH:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0/bin
#export JAVA_HOME
 export HH_CLASSPATH=.:$BASEDIR/dist/HomeHealthJava.jar:$BASEDIR/dist/HH_PPS_V_API.jar
#export CLASSPATH=${CLASSPATH}
classpath=""
input=""
config=""
export JAVA_VERSION=`java -version`                 #/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/
#temp="java -version"
#JAVA_VERSION=`java -version 2>&1 |awk 'NR==1{ gsub(/"/,""); print $3 }'`
export TEST_FILE=$BASEDIR/TestData/TestDataV6117.txt
export OPTIONS=1

  java $JAVA_VERSION -Xms512m -Xmx512m -Djava.util.logging.config.file="/home/bitsbridge/Videos/HomeHealthGrouper/config/logging.properties"\
            classpath="/home/bitsbridge/Videos/HomeHealthGrouper/dist/HomeHealthJava.jar:/home/bitsbridge/Videos/HomeHealthGrouper/dist/HH_PPS_V_API.jar"  com.mmm.cms.homehealth.test.HomeHealthGrouper_HP\
            input="/home/bitsbridge/Videos/HomeHealthGrouper/TestData/TestDataV6117.txt" config="/home/bitsbridge/Videos/HomeHealthGrouper/config/HomeHealthGrouper.properties"\
            $OPTIONS


 export BASEDIR=""
 export HH_CLASSPATH=""
 export TEST_FILE=""
  export OPTIONS=""

 #${CLASSPATH}:.
 #com.mmm.cms.homehealth.test.HomeHealthGrouper_HP
```

**WHEN ABOVE CODE IS EXECUTED IT IS GIVING ERROR:**

> Error: Could not find or load main class 
>   classpath=.home.bitsbridge.Videos.HomeHealthGrouper.dist.HomeHealthJava.jar:.home.bitsbridge.Videos.HomeHealthGrouper.dist.HH_PPS_V_API.jar

But while executing it is not able to load the jar files mention in the classpath and it's giving the error:

> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)  Java HotSpot(TM)
>   Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)  Error: Could not find or load
>   main class
>   classpath=.home.Desktop.HPPP.HomeHealthGrouper.dist.HomeHealthJava.jar:.home.D
>   esktop.HPPP.HomeHealthGrouper.dist.HH_PPS_V_API.jar

**P.S: I have already check the java path.**

This is the content of **/etc/environment/:**

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/$
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle"
```

please help finding the problem.I am stuck here over a week

**I have update the above mention shell code and code is issue free as checked at shellcheck.net:**

```
 #!/bin/bash
 BASEDIR=/home/Desktop/HPPP/HomeHealthGrouper
 FILE=/home/Desktop/HPPP/HomeHealthGrouper/config/logging.properties

 export HH_CLASSPATH=.:/home/Desktop/HPPP/HomeHealthGrouper/dist/HomeHealthJava.jar:.:$BASEDIR/dist/HH_PPS_V_API.jar
 JAVA_VERSION="$(java -version)"            
 export JAVA_VERSION
 export TEST_FILE=$BASEDIR/TestData/TestDataV6117.txt
 export OPTIONS=1

 java "$JAVA_VERSION" -Xms512m -Xmx512m -Djava.util.logging.config.file="$FILE"\
 -classpath="/home/Desktop/HPPP/HomeHealthGrouper/dist/HomeHealthJava.jar:/home/Desktop/HPPP/HomeHealthGrouper/dist/HH_PPS_V_API.jar" com.mms.cms.homeHealth.test.HomeHealthGrouper_HP\
 "input=/home/Desktop/HPPP/HomeHealthGrouper/TestData/TestDataV6117.txt" "config=/home/Desktop/HPPP/HomeHealthGrouper/config/HomeHealthGrouper.properties"\
 $OPTIONS


 export BASEDIR=""
 export HH_CLASSPATH=""
 export TEST_FILE=""
 export OPTIONS=""
```

**This the output after execution of above code:**

> - ./javaaad.sh
>     java version "1.7.0_80"
>     Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
>     Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)
>     Error: Could not find or load main class

**Getting an error:**

> Error: Could not find or load main class

Comment: Couldn't find what the problem is.. Run the script thru [\[ shellcheck \]](https://www.shellcheck.net/)

Comment: I am not sure what the downvote is for. Downvoting without a reasonable comment doesn't help. :-( imho

Comment: thanks for the website.There is little bit structure change.Hope it works thanks sjsam

Comment: even I don't know the reason for downvote.

Comment: @mpk24  Hmm. If you're new to bash then *shellcheck* is an invaluable tool. Also feel free to use `bash -x` to debug your scripts. Good luck :-)

Comment: Did you veryify that there indeed is a class having a *public static main*? Also it is strange that you are defining a variable `HH_CLASSPATH`, but don't use it anywhere.

Comment: I was using it to pass the path to classpath. classpath="$HH_CLASSPATH" , but i was testing it by passing the path directly.

Comment: `-classpath "..."` without `=`

Comment: @apangin returning an error:could not find or load main class.

Answer (score 0):

Add hyphen in front of classpath switch: `classpath=...` => `-classpath=...`.

```
java -h
...
-classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
              A : separated list of directories, JAR archives,
              and ZIP archives to search for class files.
...
```

Also change `java $JAVA_VERSION ...` to `java ...` because now you have empty sting in variable `$JAVA_VERSION` causing extra argument `java '' ...`. `java -version` prints nothing to stdout and multiline version description to stderr.

Comment: not helping.Error: Could not find or load main class

Comment: run `bash -x yourscript` and copy-paste result to pastebin.com

Comment: https://pastebin.com/CPY6B7SE . I have uploaded both shell code and output of bash -x here.

Comment: I think i need the JAVA_VERSION but need to change it with something else which i am not able to figure out after removing $JAVA_VERSION getting an error:                                                                                        > Unrecognized option: -classpath=.:/home/Desktop/HPPP/HomeHealthGrouper/dist/HomeHealthJava.jar:.:/home/Desktop/HPPP/HomeHealthGrouper/dist/HH_PPS_V_API.jar                       >Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
>Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Comment: `-version` switch sets requirement for the java version to be used. There is no sense to detect it first and then require detected version. Either put some constant value into it or leave it out.

Comment: JAVA_VERSION=1.7.0_80  set to this still same error. Error: Could not find or load main class 1.7.0_80

Comment: can you please review the batch code. The rem ask to set java version  but in this case it's problematic as i dont know what to put there.

Comment: Batch has no quotes in `%JAVA_VERSION%` and it is replaced with nothing (causing no extra empty `''` argument) and that's why it works if setting value is commented out with rem. If you have `JAVA_VERSION=1.7.0_80` replace `java "$JAVA_VERSION"` with `java -version "$JAVA_VERSION"`.

Comment: its running without error but not giving any output. If I am using java -version.... then there is no error and its priting the java version and code execute without error and if I am using java -version "$JAVA_VERSION" it's printing the version twice and exiting. But not doing its intended purpose which is to read text file and produce xml file.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot colon (`:`). Replace `java "$JAVA_VERSION"` with `java -version:"$JAVA_VERSION"`.

Comment: giving Error: Syntax error in version specification "" so i guess not to use that.

Comment: java $JAVA_VERSION -Xms512m -Xmx512m -Djava.util.logging.config.file="$FILE"\
  -classpath "$HH_CLASSPATH" com.mms.cms.homeHealth.test.HomeHealthGrouper_HP\
  "input=/home/Desktop/HPPP/HomeHealthGrouper/TestData/TestDataV3413.txt" "config=/home/Desktop/HPPP/HomeHealthGrouper/config/HomeHealthGrouper.properties"\
   $OPTIONS                                                                                               **This part is giving error:Error: Could not find or load main class com.mms.cms.homeHealth.test.HomeHealthGrouper_HP**

Comment: Run again `bash -x yourscript` and copy-paste java command here.

Comment: You still have `java -version '' ... `. If you have no value in `$JAVA_VERSION` leave it out. If you have value, use `-version:"$JAVA_VERSION"`.

Comment: I am using -version " " now but file is not giving any error and neither any output

Comment: You have forgotten colon (`:`, see my previous comment) but I suggest to leave out all the `-version:...` switch because it is deprecated and removed in Java 9.

Comment: if i use colon then i am getting error Error: Syntax error in version specification ""
so i guess it will run without colon but there is some other problem as output file is not generating.

Comment: You can't use `-version:...` with empty parameter value. You can't use it without colon... or usage (no extra parameter) and meaning (to print out version information instead of requiring certain version) without colon is different.

Comment: java -version "" -Xms512m -Xmx512m -Djava.util.logging.config.file="$FILE"\
  -classpath "$HH_CLASSPATH" com.mms.cms.homeHealth.test.HomeHealthGrouper_HP\
  input="/home/Desktop/HPPP/HomeHealthGrouper/TestData/TestDataV7118.txt" config="/home/Desktop/HPPP/HomeHealthGrouper/config/HomeHealthGrouper.properties"\
   $OPTIONS                                                                                                       **Not giving any error but i can keep it empty i guess coz when i put colon it give the error an dwhen i put $JAVA_VERSION its running with same functionality.**

Comment: :) still `-version` without colon and with empty parameter value. It is different switch without colon causing cmd to print out version, not executing the code. Just leave all the version switch out, because it won't work with Java 9.

Comment: if i am putting -version="1.7.0_80". I am getting an **Error: Unable to locate JRE meeting specification "1.7.0_80"**

Comment: Maybe your Java version is not 1.7.0_80. Run just a command `java -version` and see the version information. What's the point to require exactly that specific version? I understand requiring 1.7 if the program does not work with other versions but 1.7.0_80 is too specific. Your script stops working if a security patch is installed and _80 changes.

Comment: its mention int batch file if i am completely eliminating -version and code is:                                       java -Xms512m -Xmx512m -Djava.util.logging.config.file="$FILE"\
  -classpath "$HH_CLASSPATH" com.mms.cms.homeHealth.test.HomeHealthGrouper_HP\
  input="/home/Desktop/HPPP/HomeHealthGrouper/TestData/TestDataV7118.txt" config="/home/Desktop/HPPP/HomeHealthGrouper/config/HomeHealthGrouper.properties"\
   $OPTIONS
**Then getting an error :Error: Could not find or load main class com.mmm.cms.homehealth.test.HomeHealthGrouper_HP.class**

Comment: Run `unzip -t jarfile | fgrep test/HomeHealthGrouper` for those jar files and see if the class is found. If it is not in those two jar files JVM can't find them.

Comment: class exist inside HomeHealthGrouper still its not loading it is there any parameter i should mention.